# Excel Accounting Format - Indian Style

Tags: excel

Indian style number formatting works with Lakhs and Crores.
A Lakh is "100,000" in US Style, but would be "1,00,000" in Indian Style.
A Crore is "10,000,000" in US Style, but would be "1,00,00,000".

I have not been able to figure out the custom number formatting syntax sufficiently to be able to do the following:

- Accounting Style currency is left justified
- Negative numbers in red
- number formatting described above

How can I do this?

I don't think it will change anything in this case, but I am on Excel for Mac (Office 365 Version).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-change-the-separator-comma-in-Excel-from-millions-to-lakhs-and-vice-versa):

1. Select the cell
2. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
3. Numbers > User Defined
4. Write this:

---

```
[>=10000000]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>=100000] ##\,##\,##0;##,##0
```

or

```
[>=10000000]"RS "##\,##\,##\,##0;[>=100000]"RS " ##\,##\,##0;"RS "##,##0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see a way of adding the second part of the question (negative numbers in red) without adding a couple of conditional formatting rules:

Format values where the formula is true

```
=A1<=-100000
```

With number format

```
[<=-10000000]##\,##\,##\,##0;[<=-100000] ##\,##\,##0;0
```

( or just

```
[<=-10000000]##\,##\,##\,##0;##\,##\,##0
```

since you already know it's <=-100000)

and

Format values where the formula is true

```
=A1<0
```

With number format

```
##,###;##,###;##,###
```

and also set font to red in both cases.

The issue was that the first format always displays minus signs for negative numbers > -100000. If you didn't mind the minus signs appearing as well as the red font, you could use

```
[<=-10000000]-##\,##\,##\,##0;[<=-100000]-##\,##\,##0;-##,###
```

for all of them.

[image]

BTW I'm testing this on Excel 2010 so 365 may be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way.
[>9999999] _ [$₹-en-IN] * ##,##,##,##0_ ;[>99999] _ [$₹-en-IN] * ##,##,##0_ ;_ [$₹-en-IN] * ##,##0_ ;_ @_

it will make Symbol to appear left alligned like usual accounting format, and make numbers appear on right side

Comment: Excel complains when I paste this into the format cell (not a valid format)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you format via custom method, one cannot do any calculations on them! Regional setting is useful if you always deal in INR, but not otherwise. Need some solution for this please.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).