# How to create a two digit comma separated number format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ms-office, excel-2007

I need to format numbers in excel as below:

> 1,00,00,00,000/-  for positive number
>
> -1,00,00,00,000/-   for negative number
>
> no character   for zero

I tried but failed! I am using excel 2007.Could any one help for all version of excels?
How to do?

Comment: 2 questions, is that formatting for presentation purposes only (no calculations afterwards)? what are the original numbers?

Comment: Presentation and calculation both!

Comment: this will add unnecessary commas while number is only one digit!!

Comment: There was a similar (not identical) question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232053/excel-accounting-format-indian-style/49235045#49235045 - had to use a combination of default format and conditional format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`###,###,###,###,##0\/\-;-###,###,###,###,##0\/\-;""`

does the jobs! But

`[>=10000000000]##\,##\,##\,##0\/-;[<=10000000000]##\,##\,##\,##0\/-;""`

places unnecessary commas while the number is only one digit in length.

Thank you! But you need to tinker with regional grouping system for number and currency, llike `10,00,00,00,000`, as described at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/thousand-formating-split-number-by-2-digits/1e347f40-4784-4033-b4e3-096b0c9cb5f4

Comment: It's useful to know about the regional grouping setting - glad the previous answer was helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working on formats,
Change Region to English India in Region settings
And change format to Numbers with Comma
Will do the Job